# Mac Leopard Server Apache Permission Denied

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, mac

I've setup the web server successfully on Mac Leopard Server and sites work fine within the DocumentRoot directory.  I have mounted a volume which has restricted access to users within a group.

I would like to point the web server to directories within this volume.  Can I add the user the web service is using to the group that has access to this Volume, if so: how do I find out what the user is?

I can confirm the web server is pointing to the right directory as log files show the full directory path.  When you access the site's URL, it shows Access Forbidden.

Comment: did you take a look at the error_log? what does it say?

Comment: Hi Marco,

Permission denied: access to / denied
Permission denied: access to /index.php denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was due to the full path (including the parent folder and it's children) didn't have appropriate permissions.